# Sort [Dictionary<String, Any>] in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm new to Swift 3 and I have this array of dictionaries in Swift 3:

```
var arrayPOIsLoaded = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()
```

And I want to sort it by the Key "name" of the dictionary.

I have look here but nothing seem to work.

I have tried to use predicates but whit no success.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is simply `arrayPOIsLoaded.sort { $0["name"] as! String < $1["name"] as! String }` If all dictionary not having `name` key then `arrayPOIsLoaded.sort { ($0["name"] as? String ?? "") < ($1["name"] as? String ?? "") }`

Comment: @NiravD I have tried this: self.arrayPOIsLoaded.sorted(by: { $0["name"] as! String < $1["name"] as! String }) but says Expected Type

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like you should have an array of some model type rather than an array of dictionaries. Doing so would eliminate the force casting and string keys (i.e make your data structure strongly typed instead of *stringly* typed ;) ).

Comment: What;s the type of the value of key "name"? String?

Comment: @Tj3n yes is a string

Comment: @MarcoAntonioUzcateguiPescoz Write it like this `array.sort { ($0["name"] as! String) < ($1["name"] as! String) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all.

This is the correct way of writing it:

```
self.arrayPOIsLoaded.sorted { ($0["name"] as! String) < ($1["name"] as! String) }
```

You have to add ()

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var arrayPOIsLoaded = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
let sortedArray = arrayPOIsLoaded.sorted {$0["name"]! as? String < $1["name"]! as? String}
```

Comment: Give me a error "Binary operator can not be applied to two Any"